# Run ansible playbook from docker container and deploy on host machine

Tags: docker, ansible

I would like to run ansible playbook on my local machine using ansible from a docker container.
Here is what my Ansible Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

WORKDIR /ansible

RUN apk update \
    && apk add ansible

ENTRYPOINT ["ansible-playbook"]
```

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
  - osx
```

roles/osx/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Welcome
  shell: echo "Hello"
  when: ansible_distribution == 'MacOSX'
```

Then I run it with:

```
docker build -t ansible_image:latest .
docker run --rm --network host \
-v $(pwd):/ansible \
ansible_image:latest ansible/playbook.yml
```

My host operating system is OS X. I expect that osx role will execute,
however it seems that playbook is run on alpine container.
I would like to ask how to indicate ansible in docker to deploy stuff on my local machine?

Comment: `brew install ansible` will be vastly easier.  In this setup Ansible-in-a-container needs a path to remotely execute administrative commands on the host, which probably means something like an ssh connection to `host.docker.internal`, which in turn means running an sshd on the host and pushing a valid key pair into the container.  Trying to embed a tool to administer the host in a Docker container makes everything much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Yup, it will be easier. However I would like to make my environment independent from other tools except docker and learn how to do stuff like this :) Thank you, Dave.

Comment: were you able to get this to work? maybe with net=host?

Answer (score 7):

Your playbook is targeting `localhost`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
  - osx
```

This means that Ansible is going to target the local machine (which is
to say, your Ansible container) when running the playbook.  Ansible is
designed to apply playbooks to remote machines as well, typically by
connecting to them using `ssh`.  Assuming that it's possible to
connect from your Ansible container to your host using `ssh`, you
could just create an appropriate inventory file and then target your
playbook appropriately:

```
---
- hosts: my_osx_host
  roles:
  - osx
```

If you're just starting out with Ansible, you might want to start with
the [Getting Started](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html) document and work your way from there.  You'll find documentation on that site that should walk you through the process of creating an inventory file.